# PERLLIB succesfully injected in @INC array but does not work with non-interactive shell

Tags: perl, unix, ssh, environment-variables

My goal is to inject in Perl's `@INC` array that it works **always** and in **any** condition perl could possibly be invoked

In order for this to work when `SpecialMoudle.pm` is not in the *default* `@INC` array, I added:

```
PERLLIB=/path/to/special/module
```

In the `/etc/environment` file on a Linux box and it works as sold:

```
$ perl -le "print for @INC"; perl -MSpecialMoudle -e "print qq/Yep SpecialMoudle.pm loaded\n/"
/path/to/special/module
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
.
```

and I get:

```
Yep SpecialMoudle.pm loaded
```

But when I ssh to **same** machine

```
$ ssh $(hostname -i) 'perl -le "print for @INC"; perl -MSpecialMoudle -e "print qq/Yep SpecialMoudle.pm loaded\n/"'
```

I get the same:

```
/path/to/special/module
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
.
```

But strangely I get also:

Can't locate SpecialMoudle.pm in @INC (@INC contains: **/path/to/special/module**  /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-l
inux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

And of course no output...

Now, I tried same with another Linux box with perl v5.10.1 and no problem there. On *this* box, I have perl v5.8.8 why does it not work? Especially since I **see** the **/path/to/special/module** in the error output?

**EDIT** Added for @pilcrow as I don't see any other way in StackOverflow to display raw data easily readable.

**(env | sort; which perl)** raw:

```
_=/bin/env
CVSROOT=:ext:10.20.30.40:/home/cvs/repository/
CVS_RSH=ssh
EDITOR=vi
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
HISTSIZE=1000
HOME=/home/stackop
HOSTNAME=sdcbatch2
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
LOGNAME=stackop
LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=00;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=00;32:*.com=00;32:*.btm=00;32:*.bat=00;32:*.sh=00;32:*.csh=00;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.bz=00;31:*.tz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.cpio=00;31:*.jpg=00;35:*.gif=00;35:*.bmp=00;35:*.xbm=00;35:*.xpm=00;35:*.png=00;35:*.tif=00;35:
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/stackop
PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
PERLLIB=/path/to/special/module
PWD=/home/stackop
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
SSH_CLIENT=100.101.102.103 65279 22
SSH_CONNECTION=100.101.102.103 65279 10.30.50.70 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
TERM=ansi
USER=stackop
/usr/bin/perl
```

**(ssh $(hostname -i) 'env | sort; which perl')** raw:

```
_=/bin/env
HOME=/home/stackop
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME=stackop
MAIL=/var/mail/stackop
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
PERLLIB=/path/to/special/module
PWD=/home/stackop
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT=10.30.50.70 39857 22
SSH_CONNECTION=10.30.50.70 39857 10.30.50.70 22
USER=stackop
/usr/bin/perl
```

Comment: Is adding `use lib qw( /path/to/special/module );` to your script problematic?

Comment: YES, then it would work, but the whole point of the `PERLLIB` was **not** to use the `use lib` on the command line

Comment: Please diff `env | sort; which perl` and `ssh $(hostname -i) 'env | sort; which perl'`  It's unusual that you mention PERLLIB [sic] rather than PERL5LIB.  My guess is your console login shell defines $PERL5LIB which overrides $PERLLIB and *also searches `$Config{version}` and `$Config{archname}` subdirs* (which PERLLIB does not for me under 5.10).  Might be different perls, though.  In any case, your ssh shell is setting up the environment differently.

Comment: I did a diff, PERLLIB nor PERL5LIB were never used on this system, I'm introducing the use, so that the INC array is pre-populated and I can refer to my **SpecialMoudle** knowing that it's already in INC

Comment: Yes, PERLLIB itself is set in both cases `(env | sort; which perl) | grep PERL.*LIB` and `(ssh $(hostname -i) 'env | sort; which perl') | grep PERL.*LIB` return the same `PERLLIB=/path/to/special/module`

Comment: @pilcrow, I'm not sure where I can post the raw output in easily readable way.... I'll do the run now and edit the original question for you, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100067/discussion-between-pilcrow-and-lzc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @pilcrow and the follow up chat, I 'think' I found the issue, by running:

```
$ diff <(ssh $(hostname -i) 'perl -V') <(perl -V)
40c40
<     PERLLIB="/path/to/special/module "
---
>     PERLLIB="/path/to/special/module"
42c42
<     /path/to/special/module
---
>     /path/to/special/module
```

GEEE: is it that extra space ?

```
$ cat -A /etc/environment
PERLLIB=/path/to/special/module $
```

I'm gonna confim with my sys admin with root permissions and I shall report back!

Comment: Wow.  Subtle.  Frustrating.  Nice use of GNU cat's `-A`

Answer (score 5):

To recognize /etc/environment via ssh, I believe you need to enable UsePAM in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (which has other implications I am not very familiar with).

You can add it (as `export PERL5LIB=...`) in /etc/profile, but then you need to make ssh use a login shell (`ssh foo 'sh -l -c command'`).

If your perl is at least 5.10 and has been built to do so (you can check with `perl -V:usesitecustomize`), every time perl starts it will run a systemwide sitecustomize.pl script in which you could put a `use lib ...;` statement.  See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-f*.

Comment: +1 for `sitecustomize.pl` which is the better way to do it.  However, we don't yet know enough from the OP to know what's wrong with his console login vs. ssh login environment.  (/etc/environment might already be sourced in both cases, since he sees the special `@INC` dir in both cases.)

Comment: As noted in the question this box still has  perl **v5.8.8** could that be the issue? Where `perl -V:usesitecustomize` gives `usesitecustomize='undef';` in any case `sitecustomize.pl` is **K**ool and would have be the checked answer... only in this case, it does not work ... yet.. thanks @ysth !

Comment: I thought sitecustomize was only added in 5.10, but then I would expect you to see `usesitecustomize='UNIKNOWN'`.  but in any case, it isn't enabled (and enabling it takes recompiling perl)